# Increase height of bars in VisualizerView

Tags: android, bar-chart, visualizer

I am using [this](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer) visualizerView in my app. I want to know how can i increase height of bars.

```
public class BarGraphRenderer extends Renderer
{
  private int mDivisions;
  private Paint mPaint;
  private boolean mTop;

  /**
   * Renders the FFT data as a series of lines, in histogram form
   * @param divisions - must be a power of 2. Controls how many lines to draw
   * @param paint - Paint to draw lines with
   * @param top - whether to draw the lines at the top of the canvas, or the bottom
   */
  public BarGraphRenderer(int divisions,
                          Paint paint,
                          boolean top)
  {
    super();
    mDivisions = divisions;
    mPaint = paint;
    mTop = top;
  }

  @Override
  public void onRender(Canvas canvas, AudioData data, Rect rect)
  {
    // Do nothing, we only display FFT data
  }

  @Override
  public void onRender(Canvas canvas, FFTData data, Rect rect)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.bytes.length / mDivisions; i++) {
      mFFTPoints[i * 4] = i * 4 * mDivisions;
      mFFTPoints[i * 4 + 2] = i * 4 * mDivisions;
      byte rfk = data.bytes[mDivisions * i];
      byte ifk = data.bytes[mDivisions * i + 1];
      float magnitude = (rfk * rfk + ifk * ifk);
      int dbValue = (int) (10 * Math.log10(magnitude));

      if(mTop)
      {
        mFFTPoints[i * 4 + 1] = 0;
        mFFTPoints[i * 4 + 3] = (dbValue * 2 - 10);
      }
      else
      {
        mFFTPoints[i * 4 + 1] = rect.height();
        mFFTPoints[i * 4 + 3] = rect.height() - (dbValue * 2 - 10);
      }
    }

    canvas.drawLines(mFFTPoints, mPaint);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
int size=3; 
if(mTop)
  {
    mFFTPoints[i * 4 + 1] = 0;
    mFFTPoints[i * 4 + 3] = (dbValue * size - 10);
  }
  else
  {
    mFFTPoints[i * 4 + 1] = rect.height();
    mFFTPoints[i * 4 + 3] = rect.height() - (dbValue * size - 10);
  }
}
```

You can Change the value(size)  for increasing the VisualizerView bars

Comment: it increases size but changes number of division. I try by setting size=4 for top and size=6 for bottom. It increases height but changes number of divisions.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

Just change the value (which is 10) in your code. To a larger value. I used 100 which worked nice for me. Hope that helps!

```
int dbValue = (int) (10 * Math.log10(magnitude));
```